Multiply a pyspark column with array for each row
I have a pyspark DataFrame with two columns. One is a float and another one is an array.
I know that the length of the array in each row is the same length as the the number of rows.
I want to create a new column in the DataFrame that for each row the result will be the dot product of the array and the column.
For example, for the following DataFrame:
+------------------------------------------------------------+-----+
|weights                                                     |value|
+------------------------------------------------------------+-----+
|[0.0, 5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]|34   |
|[5.0, 0.0, 5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]|50   |
|[4.0, 5.0, 0.0, 5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0]|56   |
|[3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 0.0, 5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0]|45   |
|[2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 0.0, 5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0]|34   |
|[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 0.0, 5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0]|36   |
|[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 0.0, 5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0]|45   |
|[1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 0.0, 5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0]|50   |
|[2.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 0.0, 5.0, 4.0, 3.0]|57   |
|[3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 0.0, 5.0, 4.0]|39   |
|[4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 0.0, 5.0]|48   |
|[5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 0.0]|39   |
+------------------------------------------------------------+-----+

I want to add a new column 'result' and the value of each row will be:
numpy.dot(row['weights'] * [34, 50, 56, 45, 34, 36, 45, 50, 57, 39, 48, 39]) 

Thanks.

You need to create a udf (user defined function), similar to how vectorisation of functions are done. Here is an example:
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType
import numpy as np

def dotting(weights, values):
    return np.dot(weights, values)

dotting_udf = udf(dotting, DoubleType())

values = [34, 50, 56, 45, 34, 36, 45, 50, 57, 39, 48, 39]
row = row.withColumn('weights', dotting_udf(df['weights'], values))

See https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.udf.html

thanks, but I want to do it without collecting the value column.

You may achieve that with a UDF function, like below:
%python
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType, ArrayType
import numpy as np


# Define a function to calculate the dot product
def dot_product(weights, value):
    return [weights[i] * value for i in range(len(weights))]

dot_product_udf = udf(dot_product, ArrayType(FloatType()))



# load your data to df first...

# create new column
df = df.withColumn("result", dot_product_udf(df["weights"], df["value"]))
df.show()

I test it in my env and it will output like:
+--------------------+-----+--------------------+
|             weights|value|              result|
+--------------------+-----+--------------------+
|[0.0, 5.0, 4.0, 3...|   34|[0.0, 170.0, 136....|
|[5.0, 0.0, 5.0, 4...|   50|[250.0, 0.0, 250....|
|[4.0, 5.0, 0.0, 5...|   56|[224.0, 280.0, 0....|
|[3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 0...|   45|[135.0, 180.0, 22...|
...


Using your code I get the dot product of the weights array of each row  with the scalar value of each row.
For example, for the first row I get [0, 5*34, 4,34, 334, ...]

It is not working for me. Can you please explain what makes the code take the entire column "value" and only the relevant row of "weights"?

answer edited,  I thought you want sum value before
